# Google analytics call then redirect in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-analytics

I am kinda new in javascript and I have a question about async calls. For example:

```
_gaq.push(['_xxyyz', 'xyz']);
window.location.href = "www.wwwwww.com";
```

Is this a valid code? Will the _gaq.push analytics code run properly and I won't interrupt the call with the redirect? Because our analytics shows invalid data, and this is the only suspicious area in the javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5554599/787464)

So the trick is to wrap your redirect in the `_gaq.push()` function, since these functions are executed in sequence.

```
_gaq.push(['_xxyyz', 'xyz']);
_gaq.push(function(){
   window.location = 'MY REDIRECT URL';
});
```

More information in the official [google Analytics documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#PushingFunctions)

Comment: FYI, if the `['_xxyyz', 'xyz']` command being pushed is something that records data (like `_trackPageview`, `_trackEvent`, `_trackTrans`...), the data may not get recorded. The problem is that the while the `['_xxyyz', 'xyz']` command may return, the tracking pixel request to record the data may not have been sent before the page redirect.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12786181/787464) one says that it should work without a timer, but you may be right.